# Lightning aura components not rendering as expected

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, js, caching

We have a few Aura components in managed package application. There are few drop down selection inputs, few buttons to redirect from one page to another page etc..
Issue is that these input values are not working as expected sometime.

1. Drop down is not filling the rows "onselect". It is Not happening all the times. We will have to refresh the screen to get it worked properly.
   [image]
   In this page, we can select the contact from the drop down(1).It will make a call to apex and gets the contact list. Here is the problem. that Email will prefill with some random old emails(2).

component HTML markup:-

```
<div>
<select class="selectEle" 
        id="{!'recCo-'+recipient.rowCount}" 
        onchange="{!c.changedRecipContact}">
    <option selected="selected" 
            value="None">--None--</option>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.consList}" 
                    var="cons">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!(recipient.contact.Id == cons.id)}" >
            <option selected="selected" 
                    value="{!cons.id}">{!cons.name}</option>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <option value="{!cons.id}">{!cons.name}</option>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
    </aura:iteration>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
changedRecipContact : function(component, event, helper){
    var listName = 'recipient';
    var selectId = event.target.id;
    
    component.set("v.loadScreen",true);
    helper.onChangeContact(component, event, listName, selectId);
},
```

Helper :

```
onChangeContact : function (component, event, listName, selectId){
    var wrapperList = '';
    if(listName === 'contact'){
        wrapperList = JSON.stringify(component.get("v.contactList"));
    }
    else if(listName === 'recipient'){
        wrapperList = JSON.stringify(component.get("v.recipientList"));        
    }
    console.log('selected row:: '+ selectId);
    var rowInd = selectId.substring(6);
    var selectedContactId = document.getElementById(selectId).value;
    console.log('selected contact ID:: '+ selectedContactId+' rowCount:: '+rowInd);
    
    var action = component.get("c.contactChanged");
    action.setParams({"conList":wrapperList,
                      "contactId":selectedContactId,
                     "rowCount":rowInd});
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var state = a.getState();
        console.log('state from contactChanged:: '+state);
        if(state === "SUCCESS"){
            if(listName === 'contact'){
                component.set("v.contactList",a.getReturnValue());
            }
            else if(listName === 'recipient'){
               component.set("v.recipientList",a.getReturnValue());        
            }
        }
        component.set("v.loadScreen",false);
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

2. Lightning buttons will do nothing happens. Let's say there is Continue button which will redirect to another page, It will do nothing and will not show any error messages. This is also happening a few times.
   [image]
   Even after clicking on CONTINUE button on this page, it will do nothing sometimes.
   Component:

   <lightning:button label="Continue"
   title="Save selected Data"
   onclick="{!c.sendUpdatedDetails}"
   class="customButton"/>

Controller :

```
sendUpdatedDetails : function(component, event, helper){
    var isError = false;
    var templateId = component.get("v.templateId");//component.get("v.recordId");
    var tempTitle = component.find("tempName").get("v.value");
    var tempDesc = component.find("tempDes").get("v.value");
    var isRequester = component.get("v.isRequester");
    var isDisabled = component.get("v.isDisabled");
    var numberOfRecipients = component.find("NumberOfRecip").get("v.value");
    if(tempTitle == undefined || tempTitle == ''){
        isError = true;
        window.alert('Please Specify a Template Name.');
    }
    if(tempDesc == undefined || tempDesc == ''){
        isError = true;
        window.alert('Please Specify a Template Description.');
    }
    if(numberOfRecipients == undefined || tempDesc == null){
        isError = true;
        window.alert('Please enter valid number of recipients');
    }
    var action = component.get("c.sendFieldsDataToEsign");
    action.setParams({"templateId":templateId,
                      "templateTitle":tempTitle,
                      "templateDesc":tempDesc,
                      "numberOfRecipients":numberOfRecipients,
                      "isRequester":isRequester,
                      //"isDisabled":isDisabled,
                      "selectedFields":component.get("v.selectedFieldsArray"),
                      "isCopyTemplate":component.get("v.isCopyTemplate")});
    action.setCallback(this, function(a) {
        var state = a.getState();
        console.log('Status from sendFieldsDataToEsign:: '+state);
        if(state=='SUCCESS' && !isError){
            var tempId = a.getReturnValue();
            console.log('templateID:: '+tempId);
            if(tempId.includes("ERROR")){
                component.set("v.showErrorMessage",true);
                component.set("v.errorMessage",tempId);
                var cmpTarget = component.find('Modalbox');
                $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fade-in-open');
                var cmpback = component.find('Modalbackdrop');
                $A.util.addClass(cmpback, 'slds-backdrop--open'); 
            }else{
                var reDirUrl = '/apex/blusign__DocTemplateIframeVF?docTempId='+tempId+'&isTemplateEdit='+(!component.get("v.isCopyTemplate"));
                console.log('reDirUrl is:: '+reDirUrl)
                var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                if(urlEvent){   
                urlEvent.setParams({
                      "url": reDirUrl
                    });
                    urlEvent.fire();
                }else{ 
                    window.location = reDirUrl;
                } 
            } 
            
        }
        
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

I observed this on dev org as well as in target orgs. This kind of behavior can repeat on some other places too.
Is this because of Caching issue or am I doing anything wrong? Please assist me with this issue. Thank you.